# JWPlayer show only Apple HLS with my smil file in wowza

Tags: jwplayer, rtmp, wowza, http-live-streaming, smil

I am using wowza streaming engine and jw player to show the stream and working fine. But i want to control bitrate of a video so that user can see the video without much buffering.
So i searched in stackoverflow and found following link.
[why smil file is not working with rtmp both in wowza and jwplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32178798/why-smil-file-is-not-working-with-rtmp-both-in-wowza-and-jwplayer)

I'm Using JWplayer pro 6.0.2813 and wowza 4.3

Here is my test.smil file

```
<smil>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <switch>
    <video src='mp4:test_49152.mp4' system-bitrate='49152' title='192x108'/>
    <video src='mp4:test_114688.mp4' system-bitrate='114688' title='256x144'/>
    <video src='mp4:test_184320.mp4' system-bitrate='184320' title='320x180'/>
    <video src='mp4:test_339968.mp4' system-bitrate='339968' title='480x270'/>
    <video src='mp4:test_544768.mp4' system-bitrate='544768' title='640x360'/>
    <video src='mp4:test_987136.mp4' system-bitrate='987136' title='854x480'/>
    </switch>
</body>
</smil>
```

and my js code:

```
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    type: 'smil',
    playlist: [{
        image: "/images/myPoster.jpg",
        sources: [{
            file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil/manifest.mpd"
        },{
            file: "rtmp://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil" //Adobe RTMP . not work
        },{
            file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil/jwplayer.smil" //Adobe RTMP . not work
        },{
            file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil/manifest.f4m"
        },{
            file: "rtsp://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil"
        },{
            file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil/playlist.m3u8" //this work fine!
        }]
    }],

    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    primary: "flash",
    stretching: "uniform"
});
```

it's totally work fine in Apple device but show **black screen** in **android** and **desktop browser**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realize that `type: 'smil'` belongs to another version and there is no need to add it.
just use this:

```
playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: [{
    image: "/images/myPoster.jpg",
    sources: [{
        file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil/playlist.m3u8"
    },{
        file: "http://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/smil:test.smil/jwplayer.smil"
    },{
        file: "rtsp://173.244.173.196:1935/vod/test.mp4"
    }]
    }],
    width: '100%',
    aspectratio: "16:9",//Common values are 16:9, 24:10 or 4:3
    primary: "flash",
    stretching: "uniform"//stretching (uniform,fill,exactfit,none)
});
```

if you have any idea about improved config please **advise me**.